# Qemu Snappy 15.04: How to tune sysctl.conf?

Tags: ubuntu-core, etc, nano

I was able to start & login into Snappy Ubuntu 15.04.
However, doing:

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

is NOT permitted.

How am I suppose to tune my own kernel and make changes to 
/etc for performance and security?

Also. How to install nano editor to replace the OLD vi?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "OLD" ... :)

```
ubuntu@localhost:~$ vi -version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb 18 2016 12:05:46)
```

7.4  is the latest release and the specific version we use was just recently rebuilt. In case you mean the *behavior* (i.e. no cursor key support in edit mode) you can switch to new style behavior by creating a `.vimr`c file with:

```
set nocompatible
```

I doubt a nano snap would be a good idea unless you run it completely unconfined (since it would never be able to actually write files outside of its rw-snap dir), you can use the "classic dimension" [1] to actually use `apt` to install and use such things.

Changing `/etc/sysctl.conf` is definitely a missing feature, it should should actually be manageable. I filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1552679 for this.

(Note that I'm talking about xenial here, 15.04 images will go out of support with the 16.04 release, they will not see changes or new features.)

---

[1]

```
sudo snappy enable-classic; snappy shell classic
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of modification is supposed to go in the gadget snap (https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/gadget/). I'm asking Oliver to amend my answer here to know if this file is tunable through it.

On the other question: you can make a "nano" snap that you will install on your system. For more information on how to create snaps, here is the tour (do not hesitate to explore the developer website): https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/.
The idea is that someone will come with such a snap as well for anyone to reuse.

Answer (score -1):

**PLEASE NOTE:**  The following solutions have been tested and known to work correctly and the results are reproducible; unsure why this answer was down-voted.  Hit-and-run down-voting without providing feedback does nothing to improve the quality of answers.

### Part 1 of your question: Editing /etc/sysctl.conf

You'll find the reason you can't write to ***/etc/sysctl.conf*** in the `mount` command's output (truncated below).

```
/dev/mmcblk0p4 on /writable type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/loop0 on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)
```

Ubuntu Core mounts the root filesystem as squashfs (read-only). Although other parts of the filesystem are mounted RW, sadly ***/etc/sysctl.conf*** is not on such a mount.

**SOLUTION:**

I had the same issue as you:  I needed to tune Kernel params and found the RO filesystem issue.  This is how I solved the problem (using a here-doc in a bash script) when disabling IPv6 support:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF> /etc/sysctl.d/60-ipv6-disable.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
EOF

sysctl -p --system
```

***sysctl** is a modular config where you load your changes into a file prefaced by a number, the higher of which overrides preferences in files of a lower number.

In the above example "***60-***" suggested for end-users to record their changes in.  To learn more about how to make your sysctl changes:

```
/etc/sysctl.d/README
```

### Part 2 of your question: Installing nano

**SOLUTION:**

On Ubuntu Core 16.04 I installed `nano` with:

```
snap install nano
```

Didn't puke any errors.  HTH-